# How to choose a radiobuttton without id with selenium webdriver and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to automate the navigation of a website. I cannot choose a radio button using the methods I know so I hope someone can guide me. Here is the html:

[image: radio group HTML snippet]

I have tried different versions of

```
bot.FindElementByClass("css-k2m43g-RadioWrapper ewsdbue1").Click
bot.FindElementByClass("css-njdfi2-NativeRadio ewsdbue3").Click
bot.FindElementByClass("css-34xfl3-CustomStyledRadio ewsdbue2").Click
```

but that crach the VBA.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When there is a question supposed to be solved using vba, it's unlikely there is any url to experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try css attribute = value selector

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[type=radio]").click
```

Comment: If you have more than 1 radio ? or its wrapped ?

Comment: Sorry it didn´t work. I get a divided by zero when I try a bot.FindElementByCss("[type=radio]").item(1).click so it doesn´t look like it finds anything.

Comment: why are you doing .item(1)? there isn't an item one in a single webElement. If there is more than one item you need bot.FindElementsByCss("[type=radio]").item(1).click I think.

Comment: Sorry forgot the "s" in elements (here, not in the code). But the bottom line is  FindElementByCss("[type=radio]") doesn´t work...

Comment: And what is the exact error message you get please?

Comment: bot.FindElementByCss("[type=radio]").Click gives  run time error 11. Division by zero

Comment: Is your testing tool supports xpath?

Comment: Interesting. Haven’t seen that before as result of a .click will look at later

Comment: "Is your testing tool supports xpath?" Yes xpath is available

Comment: can you share the url?